# javascript not working animated percentage bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know the reason is going to be utterly simple but I can´t make this work, I have a html, a css and a js in the same folder and this [example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/percentage-bar) is not working

I´ve placed the 3 files in the same folder like this:

html:

```
    <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="barras.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="barras.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="container">
<h2><strong>Bar percentage</strong> inspired by this <a href=
    "http://dribbble.com/shots/1090476-Percentage-Bar">dribbble shot</a></h2>

  <div id="bar-1" class="bar-main-container azure">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="38"></div>
      <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]').each(function () {
  var progress = $(this);
  var percentage = Math.ceil($(this).attr('data-percentage'));
  $({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: percentage}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      // What todo on every count
    var pct = '';
    if(percentage == 0){
      pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + '%';
    }else{
      pct = Math.floor(this.countNum+1) + '%';
    }
    progress.text(pct) && progress.siblings().children().css('width',pct);
    }
  });
});
```

and the css the same as in the example.

I guess I´m not calling the javascript correctly. This is the first time working with js.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you create a plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: Appears to return expected result at http://plnkr.co/edit/yiDgzPqEwDRaEUI67pEY?p=preview

Comment: Exactly, that´s why I don´t understand why it doesn´t work in local

Comment: Are you trying at `file:` protocol? Are any errors logged at `console`?

Comment: When including  the script in the head it works, no idea what happened. Thanks guys